# How to set up Redis Cluster Slave only for backup?

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

I'd like to add a new slave to the Redis Cluster, which has 3 masters and 3 slaves currently. But the new slave it's only for bgsave, it can't be master if the master fail-over, can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you can use the 'cluster-slave-no-failover' option as of this commit: https://github.com/antirez/redis/pull/3041/files discussed here https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/3021

Comment: Cool, do you know which version of Redis can use this option?

Comment: It seems not released yet?

Comment: Yeah sorry, didn't check the date and thought it'd been around for a while. You could build it yourself?

Comment: OK, I'll have a try.